# Locally save data from remote iPython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using an ipython notebook that is running on a remote server. I want to save data from the notebook (e.g. a pandas dataframe) locally.

Currently I'm saving the data as a .csv file on the remote server and then move it over to my local machine via scp. Is there a more elegant way directly from the notebook?

Comment: Set the save location to a shared directory maybe?

Comment: Yes, that would have been my next step as well. I was hoping there was a way to use scp directly from the notebook. I can't be the only one with this use case, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some combination of cPickle and bash magic for scp?